# React *create app* won't render when I go to localhost

Tags: node.js, reactjs, create-react-app, react-fullstack

I have spun up a React app using `create-react-app` and have my *index.js* file as below.

```
import React{ReactDOM} from "react";
import App from "/componects/App.js";

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

My *server.js* file is as

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();


app.get("/", function(req,res){
  res.sendFile("fullpath/index.js")
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log("app listening on port 3000");
})
```

I have checked my root route and it works when I don't send the full path. I do specify the full path in the code, but I want to keep it private for this post.

I do have a `jsconfig` file. When I go to localhost I receive all as plain text of the file. I only get the code itself. How can I fix this?

Comment: There must be an error. Did you check your terminal logs and the console in your browser?

Comment: yep no joy. no linter errors either

Comment: `import React{ReactDOM} from "react";` maybe here you miss a comma?
=> `import React, {ReactDOM} from "react";`

Comment: #1 change the title to: how render react with express #2 attach the startup log on your question

Comment: You have to *build* the react app, you can use `node` to serve it, but you need to serve up the index.html and all of the built code, not just one source JavaScript file.

Answer (score 1):

### Quickly answer

You are totally wrong and you are confusing technologies: [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) and [React](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(web_framework)).

Usually you cannot mix these technologies.

As a summary, Node.js **does not understand** React code, that is why the following line in your code is unexpected, crazy and will fail:

```
res.sendFile("fullpath/index.js")
```

- res.sendFile is for **Node.js** [server-side rendering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting#Server-side_rendering) (SSR)
- index.js is **React** code

If your **create-react-app** workspace is correct and standard, execute this line to start your react code in developer mode:

```
npm run start
```

If your react code is fine, the classic `http://localhost:3000` will open on your local browser.

### Long answer

#### Concepts

[Server-side rendering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting#Server-side_rendering) (SSR) — the traditional rendering method, basically all of your page’s resources are housed on the server. Then, when the page is requested (commonly from web browsers), the HTML, JavaScript and CSS are downloaded. Also frameworks can dynamically can create the HTML-based on [back end](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/back_end#Noun) logic and finally download it. At this point, a lot of frameworks offer wonders for creating apps in no time with "amazing" functionalities.

Technologies: [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29), [C#](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29), [Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29), Node.js, etc.

**Client-side rendering (CSR)** — Which is sometimes called "Frontend rendering" is a more recent kind of rendering method, this relies on JavaScript code executed on the client side (browser) via a JavaScript framework. So, when page is requested, a minimal, little or empty index.html, CSS and JavaScript content were downloaded. Here **JavaScript** is responsible to send or receive data and update a minimal section of the page **without an entire page refresh.**. Finally when user clicks or triggers some event, JavaScript code will send or receive the **data** commonly to an API [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) ([JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)) using an async call ([Ajax](https://medium.com/letsboot/basics-using-ajax-with-fetch-api-b2218b0b9691)).

Technologies: React, [Angular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_(web_framework)), [Vue.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vue.js), [Aurelia](https://aurelia.io/), [jQuery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery), pure JavaScript, etc.

**Node.js**

Is used in SSR frameworks

**React.js**

- Is a CSR framework
- Webs developed with React are called [SPAs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) (single-page applications)

#### How can a CSR web be served?

In the **developer stage** (laptop/pc) you just need to use some kind of hot reload server (usually Node.js) which translates React into  pure JavaScript code and link it to your browser.

These kind of servers are provided or developed by framework creators (Angular, Vue.js, React, etc.). Usually, they are pre-configured in your package.json as: **npm run dev** or **npm run start**

In **testing/production** stage, you should not use the hot reload server. You should perform a build which translates react into a pure JavaScript code. Usually is the command **npm run build** and the result are new files on some folder in your workspace: *index.html*, *bundle.js*, *main.css*, etc.

These files are ready to published **on any HTTP server** from minimal to a complex servers:

- [Apache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server)
- [nginx](https://gist.github.com/jrichardsz/547c09a43a3c61b82c2d385af1de0e7c#file-docker-nginx-static-server-md)
- [haproxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HAProxy)
- [Tomcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat)
- [WildFly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WildFly)
- [IIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services)
- free/paid web FTP services
- any decent server on any technology capable to serve HTML content.

#### React in the *developer* stage

If you are using **create-react-app** in a correct and standard way, there is a **start** script in your *package.json* file ready to use:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
}
```

I advice you to change it from **start** to **dev** to make it more intuitive. Let’s empty the start script to be correctly configured for the next stage.

#### React in the testing/production stage: Basic

If your React code is ready to be tested or used by real users in the real world, and your **create-react-app** workspace is correct and standard, these are the required and minimal steps:

- install a minimal Node.js HTTP server

  - `npm install http-server --save`
- add this in your script **main**:

  - `"start": "http-server ./build"`
- execute `npm run build`
- if there is no errors and your static files are created (*index.html*, CSS, JavaScript, etc.), perform:

  - `npm run start`

For more information (custom port, etc.) check this minimal Node.js HTTP server implementation:

- *[http-server: a simple static HTTP server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server)*

#### React in Testing/Production stage: Docker

If your *package.json* has correctly configured the standard scripts:

- npm run build
- npm run start (with *http-server* or another)

You could use Docker to deploy it on any Linux server in this universe:

```
FROM node:10
COPY . /opt/
WORKDIR /opt/
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build
ENV PORT 8080
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["npm","run","start"]
```

Linux is the only option for real environments. **Windows and Mac are just for the developer stage**

#### React in the testing/production stage: Advanced server

What if your requirement needs:

- user sessions
- login/logout feature
- user inactivity expiration
- [JWT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token) [OAuth 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth#OAuth_2.0) token refresh
- any other feature that React or any CSR/SPA was not designed for

In this case you need an advanced server implemented in some technology like: Node.js, Java, Python, PHP, etc.

These implementations:

- should expose your endpoints like: `/login, /logout` ready to be called from your React, Angular, or Vue.js
- should handle the user session with any common way: memory, [Redis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redis_%28data_store%29), [MongoDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB), etc.
- offer a login: basic authentication, Google, Microsoft, etc.

My first attempt was:

https://github.com/jrichardsz-software-architect-tools/geofrontend-server

I am planning a revamp with more features and unit tests.

#### React in the testing/production stage: Advanced API/[microservices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microservices)

All of the features explained in the previous paragraph could be implemented on any back end REST API or microservice.

With that, your CSR/SPA builds will still be ***static*** and ***won’t need*** any crazy HTTP server. Just the basics as explained at the start of this answer.

Answer (score -1):

Express / Node.js is case-sensitive. You need to provide an absolute path to the file:

```js
const app = require('express')();

app.get("/", function(req,res) {
  // Absolute path
  res.sendFile("C:/Users/%username%/fullpath/index.js")
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("App listerning on port 3000");
});
```

A relative path is when you are in a directory, and specify a file without specific location:

```
# Absolute path
C:/Users/John/path/to/file.txt

# Relative path
path/to/file.txt
```

Comment: I don't think this is a good advice. If absolute paths are needed, one should use `process.cwd()` or `__dirname`.

Comment: What about the React libraries? The index.html file? This will not work to serve a react app.